# Compare two MySQL tables and select distinct entries in second one

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have two MySQL tables with one column in each. I want to select the entries in second table that does not exist in the first one.

I tried the below query, but seems does not work

```
SELECT column_name FROM `table_name_1` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT column_name FROM `table_name_2`);
```

For example:
table_name_1

```
column 
111111111111
222222222222
333333333333
444444444444
```

table_name_2

```
column
222222222222
333333333333
555555555555
666666666666
```

Now, I want to get only 55555555555 and 66666666666 entries in table_name_2.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM `table_name_2` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT column_name FROM `table_name_1`);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply `Left Join` from table 2 to table 1 and get all those **unique** values, corresponding to whom no match exists in the table 1 (`t1.column_name is null`)

Also, **note that**, for performance you will need Index on both the columns in their respective tables.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.column_name  
FROM table_name_2 AS t2 
LEFT JOIN table_name_1 AS t1 ON t1.column_name = t2.column_name 
WHERE t1.column_name IS NULL
```

**Note** that if the column values are constrained to be unique (PK or Unique constraint), or you don't care if duplicate values come in result, you can remove `DISTINCT` keyword used in the above query.

---

**Result:**

```
| column_name  |
| ------------ |
| 555555555555 |
| 666666666666 |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwqNZpaugijKjXwvjWHJi7/0)

Comment: Both tables are so large and the query took few hours running without a result.

Comment: @AhmedMaher do you have any indexing defined on the tables ?

Comment: No, both tables are 1 column tables and that column is the primary one.

Comment: @AhmedMaher since the column is Primary Key. You can remove the `DISTINCT` from my query and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work with this. [Check fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f7a88/5)

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name 
FROM   table_name_2 
WHERE  column_name NOT IN (SELECT column_name 
                           FROM   table_name_1);
```

Comment: Also as the other solution, both tables are so large and the query took few hours running without a result.

Answer (score 0):

So some records from the second table are needed.
Then the second table must be in the outer query.

The (NOT) EXISTS criteria is different from (NOT) IN.
When using an EXISTS, the relation between the query in the EXISTS and the outer query needs to be added inside the EXISTS.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name 
FROM `table_name_2` AS t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 
     FROM `table_name_1` AS t1
     WHERE t1.column_name = t2.column_name
);
```

SqlFiddle test [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78187d/1/0)

Comment: Both tables are so large and the query took few hours running without a result.

Comment: Then I assume that there's no index on `table_name_1.column_name`. I wouldn't know about why there's no result from your real tables. Maybe t1 has a matching column_name in t2 for all?

Comment: @AhmedMaher One other trick you could try is using a temporary table with a primary key on column_name. Then insert the unique values to it. F.e. `insert into tmpTable (column_name) select column_name from table_name_1 where column_name is not null group by column_name`. Then change the query so it uses the temporary table instead. It could be faster because it could have less records, and it would be indexed on the field you try to match.

Comment: There are results, I know that. Both tables are 1 column tables and that column is the primary one.What about altering both table and adding a separate primary key column? Would that help?

Comment: @AhmedMaher I kinda assumed that your real tables would have more columns and that you simplified the issue for your question. Then why not just make that one column the primary key in both tables? You can't insert dups in it afterwards though.  Also that would open up another possible solution : the [MINUS](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus/) operator.

Comment: This one column is already the primary key in both tables. It is also the only column in the table.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.  But I think I noticed somewhere in some MySql docs that sometimes an index isn't used when the join is on 2 columns with a different size.  But I'm assuming that those 2 tables use the same datatype & size for the column. So that probably won't be it.  And splitting the queries in batches seems troublesome.